# How to change text color in com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar

Tags: android

I imported library mancj.materialSearchBar, when i start searching, the text i type  is in white color, same with the background color of materialSearchBar.The user cannot see what they have type in the searchbar. How to change the typed text color in mancj.materialSearchBar ? I have applied android:theme but seem did not have any effect...

activity_food_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FoodList"
>

<com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchBar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:mt_speechMode="false"
    app:mt_hint="Enter your food"
    app:mt_textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_food"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/searchBar"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use mt_textColor to set the text color and mt_hintColor to set the hint color for it.

Comment: such as app:mt_textColor=#000000 ?

Comment: Yes thats correct...

Comment: unfortunately, my app crash after adding that function

Comment: Can you update your code here. So that i can check what you had done.

Comment: i just added  app:mt_textColor="#000000" to the xml file and try to run it but crashed

Comment: Your code is correct. Can you share the exception that you are getting.?

Comment: sir, can u give me your email ? i will show my logcat at there and i found my error but i got no idea how to solve the error

Comment: You can email me at - surender@androhub.com

Comment: send already sir

Answer (score 0):

## Solving your problem using reflection

## Foreword

You can use reflection to get the edit text and color it. Note that it works also with the placeholder (nota: you didn't specify if you are asking for help about the actual edit text corresponding to search key words which are typed by the user, or about placeholder).

In this answer, I will show you 1) how to get the described above edit text and 2) how to get the described above placeholder, and 3) how to set text and color it. The corresponding code is bound to this answer, within the very last section.

NB: *The answer's aim is not to explain the concept of "reflection", nore to explain it in the case of Java or Android. Its sole objective is to make you able to customize the mancj/MaterialSearchBar's keywords edit text and placeholder (and, by extension, all its widgets), using reflection.*

## Steps

### Getting the widgets

Actually read the class of mancj/MaterialSearchBar, and you will see its fields list. According to your question, the interesting ones are:

1. `searchEdit`
2. `placeholder`

(Obviously, note that it will probably be (very) different from an (search *e.g.*) API to another.)

Then you can get it and make it accessible to get the corresponding `EditText` (associated to the search edit) and `TextView` (associated to the placeholder).

### Setting text and color

Once you got the adequat widgets, you can use their methods (*i.e.:* methods of `EditText` and of `TextView`) in order to set their text and color. The interesting methods are the following: `setText` and `setTextColor`.

### Going further: setting font family

One interesting thing could be to customize the font family of both placeholder and keywords edit text.

Similarly to the previous section, you can 1) get the font (`ResourcesCompat.getFont(some_context, R.font.some_font` *e.g.*) and 2) use `setTypeface` on the widget you got (`EditText` and/or `TextView`).

### Sources

Here is the corresponding sources for the search keywords edit text. The same can be done for the placeholder, following the previous explanations.

```
final Field searchEdit;
try {
    searchEdit = material_search_bar.getClass().getDeclaredField("searchEdit");
    searchEdit.setAccessible(true);
    final EditText editText = (EditText) searchEdit.get(material_search_bar);
    editText.setText("Your text");
    editText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
    Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()), R.font.your_font);
    editText.setTypeface(typeface);

} catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```